# How to configure IP phone (or Asterisk maybe) to show the name extension I'm calling for?

Tags: centos, asterisk, pbx, sip-server

I work in a callcenter, we changed our PBX from Denwa SMALL (a old asterisk version) to Asterisk 11.18 in a HP Server (Intel Xeon E5-2603v4 Six Core), I have many issues that my provider doenst know how to do it and is very slow to answer my questions. The thing is very simple, before when I called from A TO B, the display of phone A appears the name labeled of the phone B, and the Phone B received the named labeled of the phone A.

Now with the asterisk and the actual configuration, Phone B display the name 
labeled of who is calling. But when the phone A place the call, the display just show the extension number, I want the phone A show the name of the phone B.

It is just with the extensions phone, just for administrative phone.

I think there must be a way to do this, not phone by phone agenda.

Comment: Have a look at the `${CALLERIDNAME}` variable in your dial plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up the destination details somehow and then use the `CONNECTEDLINE` function in your dialplan, something like this excerpt from FreePBX's dialplan:

```
Set(CONNECTEDLINE(num,i)=${EXTEN})
Set(CONNECTEDLINE(name)=${DB(AMPUSER/${EXTEN}/cidname)})
```

In this example, the names are stored in the Asterisk database.

Once the call is initiated, the *caller* will be sent the details in a SIP message. It's up to the endpoint to work with it.

Details can be found here: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Manipulating+Party+ID+Information

Answer (score 0):

If you want display something for OUTBOUND call, use phone's phonebook or other **phone-specific** method.

No any relation to asterisk or sip provider, really

Answer (score 0):

> You could add user's name to callerid parameter in sip.conf
>
> > like :

```
[101]
type=friend
callerid="Your user's name" <101>
username=101
host=dynamic
secret=********
```

> And do a `sip reload` at CLI. It'll only work for peer to peer not on the public network

Comment: That's the opposite of what the question is looking for. They want info on the person being called to be sent to the caller.